# How can we write code using fsspec to read data from gcp on our local system

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, fsspec

I tried writing below code but facing below errors.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('data.json')

fs = fsspec.filesystem('gcs', gcs=client, token=credentials)

csv_files = fs.glob("bucket-name/*.csv")

dfs = []
for file in csv_files:
    with fs.open(file) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(df.head())
```

But when i tried writing this code...it is able to return me all bucket name on my gcp a/c but it is not able to read the different types of data file present inside this and it gives me an error of SSL.

RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.'})

Is it because i did not install google cloud cli and directly trying to use it with help of key.json.

Also when i try to install gsspec library as well it will give us some modules error. Please note: I am using 3.12 version of python in order to solve above question.

Comment: You need to specify the scope parameter to `from_service_account_file()`. For example, `scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only']` https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes

Comment: ^ this may well be right right answer - would you like to make it an answer rather than a comment @JohnHanley ?

Comment: @mdurant I don't use the GCSFuse product or Pandas with it, so I posted a comment instead of an answer as these types of posts tend to cascade with problems. I will be happy to post an answer once the OP confirms the solution.

Comment: (gcsfs = GCS file system; fuse is optional and not much used)